# Can I create recurring jobs in Dynamics CRM 2011 online?

Tags: plugins, workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Is it possible to create a plug-in in the Dynamics CRM 2011 online that calls a WebService every 30 seconds, and does this all day long?

In a normal application, I would create an infinite loop with a Thread.Sleep(30000) inside, but Dynamics CRM online does not allow this. The CRM online kills my plug-in after 2 minutes.

Is there a way to achieve my goal? Maybe some kind of timers, system jobs or workflows?

From what I found on the internet, a workflow calling itself from time to time only works if there is a pause of about 70 minutes between calls; otherwise, CRM will consider this an infinite loop and kill it after 6-7 calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Both of the limitations you've found are true. If you need to run something every 30 seconds, you'll have to find somewhere external to run it.